# Akka-SSE (deprecated Ok.feed)

Tags: playframework, akka, akka-stream, server-sent-events, eventsource

I have been working with Akka SSE and found this wonderful easy understanding of SSE using javascript in the client side.
http://runkalrun.blogspot.in/2016/01/server-sent-events-sse-using-scala-akka.html

The only problem is, the `Ok.feed()` method has been deprecated in play 2.6, though we can use `Ok.chunked()` which uses Source as a parameter.
The example uses an `Concurrent.broadcast`, which gives out the enumerated stream and a channel.
How can I use the stream and channel to chunk out events? If anyone has worked on it or even any kind of suggestion is welcomed.

p.s I'm using play Scala.